# Rcpp zeros of a quadratic equation in two variables

Tags: optimization, root, rcpp, quadratic-programming

I am new to Rcpp so I apologize in advance if this question is simple to answer. I searched on the web but couldn't find much help and I am hoping the savviness in this forum can help me!

I have an existing code in R using Rcpp, and I need to add to this code the following. I have a quadratic function in two variables, f(x, y), and I need to find the zeros of it:

```
f(x, y) = (x + by + c)' W (x + by + c)
```

where the unknowns are x and y. That is, I am interested in finding the set of pairs (x, y) that satisfy f(x , y)=0.

**Note:** This is a simulation exercise where I need to find the zeros of this function for different values of a, b, c and W. Therefore, I need to code this in a mechanical way (cannot just find the solution, for instance, by graphical inspection). Both variables are continue, and I don't want to work with a grid for (x,y) to see when f(x,y)=0. I need a more general/optimization solution. I don't really know what values (x,y) can take.

Comment: So, you need a numerical optimization routine. Try [RcppNumerical](https://github.com/yixuan/RcppNumerical#numerical-optimization).

Comment: Well, I don't need to minimize the function. I need to find the zeros or roots...

Comment: Demerit points for cross-posting rcpp-devel, particularly as you failed to give any more relevant details.

Comment: What do the notations stand for in your function? Are x, y scalars? Or vectors?

Comment: I cross posted to reach out to more people. I thought rcpp-devel may be a more specific audience. I really need help!

Comment: Good question. In the general problem, x and y are vectors, and W is a matrix. Dimensions are such that f(x,y) is scalar. I can simplify the problem and assume everything is scalar, including W. It will give a quadratic form in two scalar variables.

Answer (score 2):

Before diving into the numerical part I think you should define this question in a better way. Here I assume that `x`, `y`, and `c` are vectors, and `b` is a scalar.

A quick observation is that, if `W` is positive definite, then `f(x, y) = 0` implies that `x + by + c = 0`. If both `x` and `y` are free variables, then the solution is not unique. For example, if `(x, y)` is a solution, then `(x - b, y + 1)` (element-wise operations) is also a solution.

If `W` is indefinite, then the equation also has multiple solutions. I just give a very simple example here. Imagine that `W` is a 2x2 diagonal matrix with 1 and -1 on the diagonal. Then as long as `x + by + c = (t, t)'` for any `t`, the function value is exactly zero.

In short, under my assumption on the notations, the equation has infinite number of solutions. I believe you need additional restrictions to make it unique.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know the equation has no unique solution. That is why I am interested in finding the **set** of pairs (x, y) that satisfy f(x , y)=0. W is a non-singular positive semi-definite matrix. There is a lot of math behind the problem, which I cannot write here (derivations are long and complex). I tried to give you the essence of the problem: find the roots of a quadratic form in two variables. This solution should contemplate all possible cases, as you would do with one variable based on the discriminant. I hope this helps.

Comment: "W is a non-singular positive semi-definite matrix." -- Doesn't this imply that W is actually positive definite?